# Importing TypeScript modules

Tags: typescript

I am just trying to get my head around TypeScript,

Say I have a module `animals.ts` like this:

```
export module Animals {

    export interface Animal {
        name(): void;
    }

    export class Elephant implements Animal {

        constructor() {

        } 

        public name() {
            console.log("Elephant");
        }
    }

    export class Horse implements Animal {

        constructor() {

        }

        public name() {
            console.log("Horse");
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to use this module in another file `animals_panel.ts`:

```
import animals = require("animals")

module AnimalPanel {

    var animal = new animals.Animals.Elephant();
    animal.name();
}
```

1. It seems a bit weird to me that I have to use `animals.Animals.Elephant()`, I would have expected `Animals.Elephant()`. Am I doing something wrong or is this the correct behaviour?
2. is it possible to import `import animals = require("animals")` inside the `AnimalPanel` module (I get errors when I try to do this)?

Comment: [Documentation for imports](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you are using external modules each file is a module. So declaring a local internal module within a file e.g. `export module Animals {` leads to unnecessary double indirection.

I would code animals.ts as :

```
export interface Animal {
    name(): void;
}

export class Elephant implements Animal {

    constructor() {

    } 

    public name() {
        console.log("Elephant");
    }
}

export class Horse implements Animal {

    constructor() {

    }

    public name() {
        console.log("Horse");
    }
}
```

And then use it as :

```
import animals = require("animals")

module AnimalPanel {

    var animal = new animals.Elephant();
    animal.name();
}
```

PS: a video on this subject of internal / external typescript modules : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: I saw in angular they imported a module (let's say  `NgModule)` then they said `@NgModule({})`. What does it mean? I mean the `@NgModule` (Thanks a lot)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 types of syntaxes `export/import`:

1. (AMD style) `Require` syntax which supported in ES5:

   `var animals = require("animals");`
2. Use `import` style which started suppurts from ES6:

   `import { Elephant, Horse } from "animals";`

TypeScript supports `export =` to model the traditional `CommonJS` and `AMD` workflow. So both variants will works and I suggest to use 2nd because it more powerful mechanism.

More details about it can be found on [official the TypeScript Modules web page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).