# Can Typescript and Browserify be used together?

Tags: typescript, browserify, commonjs

I have been looking at using TypeScript and Browserify together. What I can't understand is that they both use require.  TS uses require to require other TS modules. Browserify uses requires to find other js files.

So the thing I can't understand here is that I would have to pass it through 2 compilation stages. 1 stage would compile TS to JS (with Browserfiy requires still left in). And 2nd stage would convert JS (with Browserify) to 1 big file reading for production.

How do these compilers above, know the difference between a require for Browserify and a require for TypeScript ?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but an interesting module to look at might be [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript compiler (tsc) [parses the following](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11.3.3) `require` syntax:

> import m = require("mod");

whereas normally you just write

> var m = require("mod");

The later syntax is not checked by tsc more in-depth - it's just a simple assignment for tsc. The former one is checked by tsc to verify that `mod` is a module written in TypeScript ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18556583/99256))