# AngularJS typescript export class from module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an angular with typescript application and the next situation:

generics.ts:

```
module app.generics{
    export class BaseClass{
        someMethod(): void{
            alert("doSomeMethod");
        }
    }
}
```

homeController.ts:

```
module app.home{
    class HomeController : generics.BaseClass{
        callSomeMethodBase(): void{
            this.someMethod(); // from base class
        }
    }
}

angular.module('app').controller('homeController', HomeController);
```

So i have 2 different files with two modules and I want to use the class from one module into another file and I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'BaseClass' of undefined

**So how can I inherit using the class from another typescript module?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have never used the module system provide by TypeScript but I think you have to import your module (maybe ?).

Maybe those links can help you !

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18556583/5542588

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I've already followed and tried those links.
I don't really understand how I should import my module...