# How to use a class from the same module or namespace in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example I have the following module

**Foo.Bar.ts**

```
export module Foo {
    export class Bar { }
}
```

And I want to use it in main, which also belongs to the same module

**Main.ts**

```
export module Foo {
    class MainBar {
        constructor() { 
            new Bar(); // doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

That does not work unless I import Foo.Bar.ts like following
`import * as MyFooBar from "./Foo.Bar";` and then use it in this way `new MyFooBar.Foo.Bar()`.

That's seems a bit excessive, and very different from example Java. Tell me is it the only way?

**UPDATE:**
So I found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18556583/445600), it still doesn't answer my question. And is somewhat what Roy Dictus suggested, but I guess it is the closest answer for my question for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
import {Bar} from "./Foo.Bar";
```

then use

```
var newBar = new Bar();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would work if I take out `class Bar` from the module Foo first however.

Comment: I don't understand this comment at all. This would work if you take the class out?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant if I don't wrap the class in a module then your solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript modules work like ES2015/2017 modules. At the end of the day, modules are *files* and they're loaded asynchornously.

In the other hand, modules create an *scope* like the manual module pattern implementation:

```
Foo = (function() {
    var export = {};
    export.x = 11;
})();
```

You need to use `import` because a function scope won't import other files' (i.e. *modules*) variables, functions, ... classes by default: there should be imported manually.

When you need something from other *module*, that operation is equivalent to this:

```
// File1.js
Foo = (function(export) {
    export.x = 11;

    return export;
})(Foo || {});


// File2.js
Foo = (function(export) {
    // You access the "x" variable exported from the other file on the Foo module
    export.pow2 = function() {
        return export.x * export.x;
    };

    return export;
})(Foo || {});
```

At the end of the day, you can't expect the behavior of a Java `*.jar` or .NET assembly `*.dll`, because these runtime environments run the applications or systems on a local machine and the modules are linked during runtime based on hints to local paths. For example, when `B.dll` requires `A.dll` at some point, because some class derives a class defined in `A.dll`, the runtime will load the assembly `A.dll` into memory.

Sadly, this mechanism isn't still available on JavaScript and TypeScript is transpiled into that target language for now, because your modules are just *code files*, they're not byte code or an intermediate language.

Maybe there's a hope with [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly)!

Comment: Seems for now it doesn't work then. That's too sad :(

Comment: @starcorn I would love to have this feature too :(

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the first keyword `export` denotes an *ES6 module*. And the keyword `module` should be replaced by *namespace* [since TypeScript 1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2923). We can rewrite your code with the new keyword:

```
// File Foo.Bar.ts
export namespace Foo {
    export class Bar { }
}
```

If the purpose is to organize the code, it is a bad practice to use *namespaces* and *modules* at the same time. You should choose between modules and namespaces.

## With ES6 modules

TypeScript supports the syntax of ES6 modules very well:

```
// File Foo.Bar.ts
export default class Bar { }

// File Main.ts
import Bar from './Foo.Bar';
class MainBar {
    constructor() { 
        new Bar();
    }
}
```

It is the recommended way. It will work on Node.js (using the `commonjs` module syntax in compiler options). Or, in a browser, it will work with the help of a bundler like [*Webpack*](http://webpack.github.io/) (see [a tutorial here](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/)) or a loader like [*SystemJS*](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) ([a tutorial here](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/)).

For a good introduction to the ES6 modules syntax, [read this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

## With namespaces

If you don't work with modules, do not `import` neither `export` anything at the top level:

```
// File Foo.Bar.ts
namespace Foo {
    export class Bar { }
}

// File Main.ts
namespace Foo {
    class MainBar {
        constructor() { 
            new Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

This code will work on a browser if you load the two generated JavaScript files, or if you concatenate them, for example with [*uglifyjs*](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).