# How to use namespaces with import in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, namespaces, es6-modules

I have two classes in two separate files and one extends from another. The base class contains some `import` statements using node modules. It is unclear to me why the derived class (which is in a separate file) does not recognize the base class!!!???

Can someone clarify this please?

```
// UtilBase.ts

/// <reference path="../typings/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/packages.d.ts" />

import * as path from "path"; // <---- THIS LINE BREAKS THE BUILD!!!!

namespace My.utils {

    export class UtilBase {

        protected fixPath(value: string): string {
            return value.replace('/', path.sep);
        }
   }
}
```

And then

```
// UtilOne.ts
/// <reference path="UtilBase.ts" />

namespace My.utils {

    export class UtilOne extends My.utils.UtilBase {

    }
}
```

After compiling I get:

```
src/UtilOne.ts(6,47): error TS2339: Property 'UtilBase' does not 
exist on type 'typeof utils'
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295778/how-to-use-a-class-from-the-same-module-or-namespace-in-typescript/37297485#37297485

Comment: I am not sure where the answer might be in the post, but thanks for replying.

Comment: `import * as X from ...` helped me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39473101/470749

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## A solution with *namespaces* (not recommended)

To resolve your issue, you can export your namespace:

```
// UtilBase.ts
import * as path from "path";
export namespace My.utils {
    export class UtilBase {
        protected fixPath(value: string): string {
            return value.replace('/', path.sep);
        }
   }
}
```

Then, you should be able to import it:

```
// UtilOne.ts
import {My} from './UtilBase';
namespace My.utils {
    export class UtilOne extends My.utils.UtilBase {
    }
}
```

However, if the purpose is to organize the code, [it is a bad practice to use *namespaces* and *(ES6) modules* at the same time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing). With Node.js, your files are modules, then you should avoid namespaces.

## Use *ES6 modules* without *namespaces*

TypeScript supports the syntax of ES6 modules very well:

```
// UtilBase.ts
import * as path from "path";
export default class UtilBase {
    protected fixPath(value: string): string {
        return value.replace('/', path.sep);
    }
}

// UtilOne.ts
import UtilBase from './UtilBase';
export default class UtilOne extends UtilBase {
}
```

It is the recommended way. ES6 modules prevent naming conflicts with the ability to rename each imported resource.

It will work on Node.js.

For a good introduction to the ES6 modules syntax, [read this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

## Use a file `tsconfig.json` instead of `/// <reference`

Notice: The syntax `/// <reference` is replaced by [the file `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). An example for Node.js:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After reading about a dozen posts and answers about how to use namespaces and modules, finally a post that makes things clear.

Comment: How can you prove that `it is a bad practice to use namespaces and (ES6) modules at the same time`?

Comment: @Pavel_K [In the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing): _"To reiterate why you shouldn’t try to namespace your module contents, the general idea of namespacing is to provide logical grouping of constructs and to prevent name collisions. Because the module file itself is already a logical grouping, and its top-level name is defined by the code that imports it, it’s unnecessary to use an additional module layer for exported objects."_

Comment: In a web app, you generally want to bundle everything in a small number of scripts... so namespaces make sense there.

Comment: @Paleo Then the whole namespace solution in typescript is kind of messy. The namespace and the module border should be the same. It should help remove the messy import/export story not not add some additional complexity.

Comment: I think namespaces are a great replacement for nested classes

Comment: @Paul In JavaScript (and TypeScript), classes can be nested. And a namespace can't be instantiated several times, it is not a class.

Comment: @Paleo Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks. Here is a link to nested classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32494175/10343490