# Angular 2 import typescript module

Tags: angular, typescript, typewriter

What is the best way to import TypeScript external module to Angular 2 TypeScript file?

I'll give an example:

Say I have to following TypeScript file (which was auto-generated by TypeWriter extension):

```
module TypeWriter.Templates {

     export interface IAppConfiguration {

        Environment: Environment;
    }

    export class AppConfiguration  implements IAppConfiguration  {

        Environment: Environment;

        constructor() {         
          //nothing                   
        }
    }
}
```

Environment is enum which is declared in other file like this (Also auto-generate):
Notice that both external module has the same module name.

```
module TypeWriter.Templates {

    export enum Environment {
        Dev = 1,
        QA = 2,
        Prod = 3,
    }     
}
```

And I have another Angular 2 service TS file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {    


}
```

How can I import AppConfiguration to SomeService?
Currently when tried to import it like this it doesn't work and the compiler says Common.ts is not a module:

```
import { AppConfiguration } from "./models/Common";
```

Basically I would like to be able to use SomeService without any need to write something like: import... 
In the same way that AppConfiguration now recognize Environment - because they sit in the same TypeScript module (TypeWriter.Templates) so no imports needed...

P.S I saw this related question: [Importing TypeScript modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556187/importing-typescript-modules)
But in this way I'll have to add imports to my TypeWrite auto-generated files - which will be a mess...

Comment: `module` is deprecated in favor of `namespace`.

Comment: Tried to work with namespace but still it doesn't help with the importing...

Comment: you might find [this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030656/2545680)